# PHP - Server side functions and variables?

Tags: php, function, variables, global

(PHP)

So here is what I would like to achieve.. but apparently I can't find any relevant information anywhere.

I would like my site to select a random value from my database every 5 minutes (for example: an ID from a table), and everyone that visit my site would see that same selected value, until the "server" randomly select another value 5 minutes after the last select.

So, I guess there would be a function that do the select from the database, 
but

1) where would I implement that function?

2) where would I call it? I'm not a expert in PHP, but I don't think it can be called from the client, else every client would call the function and they would not see the same value as others?

3) how do I to set a 5 minutes timer to call the function again?

In brief.

- Server select a random value (ex: an ID from a table).
- It get displayed on the site (same value from everyone for 5 minutes)
- 5 minutes after last select, another value is randomly selected
- It get displayed..
- Repeat...

I will probably use Laravel to created my website, I'm saying just in case it's important for the solution.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: write it out in a script and then create a cron job that calls that script every 5 minutes. google search cron job. Make sure you can set up a cron on your server. Some hosts don't allow it for every account type.

Comment: 1. in a file, 2. another or the same file, 3.cron

Comment: Oh yeah, I've heard of cron job, but what if it is hosted on a basic hosting services on godaddy (not private)? I don't think I can even create a cron, can I?

Comment: even most cheap shared hosts support cron jobs (p.s never host on godaddy)

Comment: okay thanks Dagon! And why not godaddy, haha. Any suggestion? :P

Comment: Godaddy does support cron jobs on Linux plans

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) As far as implementing functions goes, It is pretty simple. If you need to use your function in multiple PHP documents, place int in a separate file and use an include to bring it into the document(that the client calls):

```
<?php include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Path/To/file/phpscript.php");
```

If you only need it in one document, simple place it in in the document(that the client calls) before you use it.

2 & 3) There are "cron jobs" if you'r using Linux(I personally don't like using them), which could be used to awaken the php script every 5 minuets(in which case keep the function in its own file), but instead I would (edit: not, use cron jobs, this is a last resort)recommend another method instead. In your function(which will run when the client requests it), write the time you last requested it in to some text file, database or anything else. when the function runs, check if the written time was more than 5 minuets ago. If it was, create a new number and write a new time down. If it wasn't, fetch the old number from the database.

EDIT: Use Cron Jobs

Comment: insanely inefficient idea, instead of very standard cronjob.

Comment: yeah, I think I will go with cronjob, but thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Ok, good luck getting a cronjob to work on a Godaddy server(I tried, ONCE).

Comment: so move hots or run a query thousand\millions of time more often than nessercery, which is the better option?

Comment: Yeah, if Godaddy can't offer me what I want, I will look somewhere else, you guys have any suggestion for hosting?

Comment: Hostgator... look around and read reviews

Comment: i never suggest a particular host, there so many with so many things to consider, while i'm happy with mine, it may well not suite you.

Comment: Thank you everyone for you help!